# Geometry question on triangle

Tags: geometry

Let ABC be an isosceles triangle with AB = AC and let Γ denote its circumcircle. A point D is on the arc AB of Γ not containing C and a point E is on the arc AC of Γ not containing B such that AD = CE.   how can I prove that BE is parallel to AD.?

[image: isoceles circumcircle]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your triangle is isosceles, the circular arcs AB and AC have the same length.  Subtracting the equal lengths of arcs AD and CE, you get that arcs BD and EA have the same length, and that implies the parallelism that you want.

Comment: I was thinking about that , but why the lengthes of the  arcs  $AD $ and  $CE $ are equal ?

Comment: @Nizar The statement of the problem includes AD=CE. Even if that refers to the straight-line distance rather than the arcs, it immediately implies the corresponding statement about the arcs.

Answer (score 0):

Let call $R$ the reflection which transforms $AD$ in $EC$ (it exists since they have same length).

You have by this reflection $R$ $AC$ transformed in $DE$.

Thus $DE$ and $AB$ have the same length.

Thus $AD$ and $BE$ are parallel.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Note $|AB|=|D'E'|$.

Let $|AF|=|AD'|$, then $\angle AD'B=\angle AFC$.

Rotate $A\to D'$ and so $\angle AD'B=\angle D'AE'$.

$|D'B|=|AE'|$ so $AD' \parallel BE'$.

Comment: Your answer here seems to be missing some primes, e.g., $|AF|=|AD'|$, not $|AF|=|AD|$.  (Also, I rolled back the OP to the version with the first figure you added, because the second one included points not referred to in the question.)